# My react project don't build. Creating an optimized production build... Failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, webpack

> vuexy-react-admin-dashboard@1.0.0 build
> react-app-rewired build
> Creating an optimized production build...
> Failed to compile.
> The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilat

my project works in *npm start*, but it dosen't work npm run build

Comment: > vuexy-react-admin-dashboard@1.0.0 build
> react-app-rewired build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilat

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.